# Resuming Lua script using its C API

Tags: c, lua

Using the Lua C API 5.3, I would like to pause a script to be able to resume it later (potentially after a game state is loaded from disk).  I do not believe co-routines/yielding can be safely used because I am building the state of local variables at the beginning of scripts and I want this solution to work after the app has fully restarted.  Essentially, maintaining the original Lua state objects is not realistic.

Example script:

```
dothisfirst()
wait(10 seconds)
dothatlast()
```

Potential Solution #1: Wrapping the whole script in a co-routine; however, the entire Lua state would have to be preserved in some unique way.  This is not useful in case the script wishes to be resumed at a later date, from a saved game state or something.

Potential Solution #2: I have thought about having the Lua script manipulated, so the portion before and after any script pauses turns into a Lua script that can be executable multiple times, where on the first run it does the first part, the second and so on runs would wait for the time specified, and the last run would do the last part.  A global variable would be used to indicate the state of the machine.

Potential Solution #3: Instead of using `luaL_dostring()`, I could pre-process the script, process conditions/loops manually, and execute individual lines manually.  This seems like the simplest and safest approach.

The big kicker is making sure the solution works with nested loops.  And as stated, the solution needs to be able to resume after the app has restarted; in that the state can be saved and reloaded.

I guess I was hoping to get feedback from the community as to whether there's other solutions or if the community might have any suggestions approaching any of the above solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you are talking about Lua's coroutines, not C++'s, so I deleted the tag.

Comment: "*potentially after a game state is loaded from disk*" What *exactly* do you mean by that? It sounds like you want to be able to essentially roll-back a `lua_State` to a previous point of execution. That is, you want to be able to save the executing state, continue executing, then reload the previous state as if the later execution had never happened. That's not a thing you can just do in Lua (or indeed most scripting languages). Not generally, at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using [lua_sethook](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_sethook). You can assign a "hook function" that is called every `count` bytecode instructions. Your hook function can defer returning when you want to pause the script. You will need to maintain the hook function's stack so it can return later, which means you've moved the problem from Lua coroutines to C coroutines, or threads.

Comment: My understanding was that `lua_sethook` was more meant for debug environments. Are you saying there's no harm in using it in a production environment?  And, can the function even be leveraged to recover from a saved state on disk?

Comment: Sure, you can use it. The debug name is historical. Most user sandbox environments exclude the `debug` table from access by Lua code, but from the C interface it's common to use it for fine control over the Lua environment.

Comment: To answer the original question: any suggestions on how to recover the hook function's stack from a saved state on disk? Moreso, how to resume when the app has fully restarted. Hooking only helps determine the bytecode/line, but doesn't help with jumping back to the same location; that is, resuming.

Comment: Oh, that was not clear. I thought you wanted to save/load a game state into a running program, not save the running program itself. My answer assumes the game state is data, separate from the code, which works fine if you architect things correctly.